# conditional task YAML pipeline based on runtime variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to run a task based on the value of a variable i set at runtime.

My variable is set like:

```
 - bash: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=affected]$(npx nx print-affected --target=build --select=tasks.target.project)"
```

and then later on I want to run a task based on the value of that variable i.e

```
- ${{ if contains(variables['affected'], 'perform-ui') }}:
        - template: pipelines/sonarcloud-build.yml@pipeline-templates
          parameters:
            AppName: 'perform-ui'
            ReactAppDirectory: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/apps/
```

How can i run tasks or jobs based on the value of that variable i have set?
I have tried conditionals, job dependancies etc with no luck...